# Win32 ReadFile hangs when reading from pipe

Tags: winapi, freeze, readfile

I am creating a child process, and reading its output. My code works fine when the child process creates output (`cmd /c echo Hello World`), however ReadFile will hang if process does not create output (`cmd /c echo Hello World > output.txt`). I am only reading after the process has terminated.

Am I doing something horribly wrong? Is there anyway to do this with synchronous mode, or do I have to use asynchronous mode? All of this is happening in a seperate thread, so I dont think asynchronous mode would offer any benefit to me, unless it is the only way to get this to work. Thanks a lot!

```
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0);
SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

memset(&piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
memset(&siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(NULL, commandWideString, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo);

while(1)
{
    GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess, &processExitCode);
    if(processExitCode != STILL_ACTIVE)
        break;
    else
        Sleep(1);
}

*output = (char *)calloc(32, sizeof(char));
processOutputSize = 0;
while(1)
{
    bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, processOutputTemp, 32, &dwRead, NULL);
    if(!bSuccess || !dwRead)
        break;
    memcpy(*output + processOutputSize, processOutputTemp, dwRead);
    processOutputSize += dwRead;
    if(dwRead == 32)
        *output = (char *)realloc(*output, processOutputSize + 32);
    else
    {
        memset(*output + processOutputSize, 0, 1);
        break;
    }
}
CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
```

Comment: I've dealt with a blocking readfile, and usually it is an unclosed handle which causes the read to block. After your child process exits you could close your handle to the write end of the pipe. Does this help?

Comment: @Marcus it helps. If the process returns output ReadFile will succeed as normal. If the process does not return output, ReadFile will fail and GetLastError() will return code 109 - Error Broken Pipe. Is this expected behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You redirect the output of the process to a pipe, start the process, wait till it exits, and then read the output.

The problem is that windows buffers just a limited amount of data. So you must read the pipe while the process is still running, otherwise the process will be blocked because it cannot write any more data to the pipe.

Comment: Thank you very much Wimmel. In case anyone is wondering, he was answering the question I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816962/win32-readfile-hangs-when-reading-from-pipe

Comment: @mattburnett Sorry, I thought this was the same question, just in a different wording. I did not read it good enough. [link to other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13866158/33499)

Answer (score 21):

You should close the write end of the output pipe before you read from it, as @Marcus suggested in the comment.

`CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);`

For me this is the real answer.

Comment: I tested it and I can confirm that this is real solution.

Comment: What if I want a continuous communication between the child process and parent process? For example talking to stockfish uci over pipes.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [PeekNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a loop like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
    if (!PeekNamedPipe(stdoutPipeRead, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to call PeekNamedPipe" << std::endl;
    }
    if (bytesAvail) {
        CHAR buf[BUFSIZE];
        DWORD n;
        BOOL success = ReadFile(stdoutPipeRead, buf, BUFSIZE, &n, NULL);
        if (!success || n == 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to call ReadFile" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::string(buf, buf + n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a sleep() delay is needed between tests.